# Nginx redirects https to http on port 443 with status 302

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I have a rather peculiar problem where some of my Jenkins links are being redirected to `http` on port `443`.

Strangely this only happens to some links.

I see this in console:

```
Request URL: https://jenkins.domain.io/jenkins/pluginManager
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: 54.111.111.75:443
Referrer Policy: same-origin
```

`Response headers`:

```
date: Tue, 06 Jul 2021 08:50:54 GMT
location: http://jenkins.domain.io:443/jenkins/pluginManager/
server: nginx/1.20.0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

And then:

```
Request URL: http://jenkins.domain.io:443/jenkins/pluginManager/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 54.183.193.75:443
Referrer Policy: same-origin
```

`Response headers`:

```
Connection: close
Content-Length: 622
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 06 Jul 2021 08:50:54 GMT
Server: awselb/2.0
```

The last one is from the load balancer. I am not doing anything special in the LB, only forwarding port 80 to port 443.

Why would nginx redirect with to `http` on 443?

These are my nginx configuration files:
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf`

```
server {
#listen       80 default_server;
#listen       [::]:80 default_server;
#server_name  localhost;

allow 127.0.0.1;
allow 172.31.6.19;
server_name jenkins.domain.io;

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
    return 301 https://jenkins.domain.io$request_uri;
}

location = /jenkins/buildByToken/buildWithParameters {
  allow all;
  auth_basic off;

  proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;
  proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.domain.tld;
}

#auth_basic "Restricted";
#auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

location /jenkins {
  proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;
  proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.domain.tld;
}

location /healthcheck {
    default_type text/html;
    return 200 "<!DOCTYPE html><h2>gangnam style!</h2>\n";
}
}
```

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
    ssl          off;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

    location = /healthcheck.html {
            auth_basic off;
            empty_gif;
            break;
        }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a server configured to answer https requests on port 443 - both those configs are just for port 80? Also what's issuing the `x-content-type-options` header - can't see that configured anywhere. Are you sure there's not another server block - perhaps a `listen 443 default_server ssl` ? I'd expect to see a reference to `ssl_certificate` or an `include` that pulled this in. Perhaps one of the additional files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` or `/etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf`

Comment: Thats the strange part. I am not listening to 443. Also, nginx is not getting any requests on 443 because they go through an ALB and target group. Requests are only received on port 80 at nginx.

Comment: And this happens to only certain links. Not to all the links. I can't seem to find a connection to why only some links get redirected with `302`

Comment: Ah, it looks like it's your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf` - you have `if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
    return 301 https://jenkins.domain.io$request_uri;
}` in there, which is probably doing the redirect to https

Comment: @jaygooby Thank you. I tried removing that. But still. Same issue.

Comment: There are two instances of `proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.domain.tld;` - obviously the `https://jenkins.domain.tld` is different to your `jenkins.domain.io` but I'm not sure if this is a real config or you've edited for SO. Take those out too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234558/discussion-between-jaygooby-and-madu).